# R - rvest - scrape all data from p (directors on IMDb page)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to **scrape** film details from IMDb webpage.
Problem is with Directors data. I'm able to **scrape** only first director, but would like to **scrape** all of them for each film.

On mentioned below page on Position 10 we have "Avengers - Infinity War" where as Directors there are Anthony Russo and Joe Russo.

Original version of the code.
As you can see there is specific child set as 1, so it reads first director.

```r
directors_data<- html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.text-muted+ p a:nth-child(1)')
directors_data <- html_text(directors_data)
```

I can change it to 2, but result will be that most of rows will be empty, as there is only one director mentioned. And only few films has more than one director.

I have tried to update the code.

```r
director_data<- html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.text-muted+ p a')
director_data <- html_text(director_data)
```

But it also reads only first entry.

Whole code

```r
library(rvest)

url<-"https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="

ile<-seq(from=1, by=250, length.out = 2)

filmy_df=data.frame()

for (j in ile){
  #otworzenie strony w przegladarce
  newURL<-"https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="
  startNumberURL<-paste0(newURL,j)
  
#odczytanie kodu strony
strona_imdb<-read_html(startNumberURL)

#ograniczenie do czesci zawierajacej szczegoly
szczegoly_filmu <- html_nodes(strona_imdb, '.lister-item-content')

#odczytanie sekcji z rankingiem
rank_data<-html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.text-primary')
#konwersja rankingu na text
rank_data<-html_text(rank_data)
#usuniecie przecinka rozdzielajacego tysiace
rank_data<-gsub(",","",rank_data)
#konwersja na numeric
rank_data<-as.numeric(rank_data)

link<-html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.lister-item-header a')%>%html_attr(.,'href')
link<-url_absolute(link,"https://www.imdb.com")

#odczytanie unikatowego IMDBid (tytuly moga sie powtarzac, a linkow nie bedziemy zliczac)
imdbID<-sapply(strsplit(link, '/'),function(x) x[5])

#odczytanie tytulu
title_data<-html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.lister-item-header a')
#konwersja tytulu na text
title_data<-html_text(title_data)
#title_data<-as.character(title_data)


directors_data<- html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.text-muted+ p a:nth-child(1)')
directors_data <- html_text(directors_data)

director_data_h<- html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.text-muted+ p a')
director_data <- html_text(director_data_h)


#utworzenie tymczasowej ramki dla iteracji
filmy_df_temp<-data.frame(Dir=director_data,Rank=rank_data,IMDBid=imdbID,Title=title_data,Directors=directors_data)

#wczytanie df z iteracji do koncowej ramki
filmy_df<-rbind(filmy_df,filmy_df_temp)
}
```

There is no any error as such. Just would like to expand functionality.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values by string manipulation after applying the `html_text()`. Even if it looks like a little bit messy, it solves the problem.

```
...
   ...

directors_data  <-  szczegoly_filmu %>% 
                    html_node('.text-muted+ p') %>% 
                    html_text()%>%
                    gsub("[|]","",.) %>%
                    gsub(".*Directors:","",.)  %>%  
                    gsub(".*Director:","",.) %>%
                    gsub("Stars:.*","",.)%>% 
                    gsub("[\n]", "", .) %>%  
                    gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", .)
...
   ...
```

gives,

```
                   Dir Rank    IMDBid                             Title                                     Directors
1            James Wan    1 tt1477834                           Aquaman                                     James Wan
2        David Raymond    2 tt6533240                             Nomis                                 David Raymond
3      Bob Persichetti    3 tt4633694 Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse Bob Persichetti, Peter Ramsey, Rodney Rothman
4    Quentin Tarantino    4 tt0361748              Inglourious Basterds                             Quentin Tarantino
5    Quentin Tarantino    5 tt0110912                      Pulp Fiction                             Quentin Tarantino
6      Andy Muschietti    6 tt1396484                                It                               Andy Muschietti
7  Lesli Linka Glatter    7 tt0114011                      Now and Then                           Lesli Linka Glatter
8         Bryan Singer    8 tt1727824                 Bohemian Rhapsody                                  Bryan Singer
9    Quentin Tarantino    9 tt3460252                 The Hateful Eight                             Quentin Tarantino
10       Anthony Russo   10 tt4154756            Avengers: Infinity War                      Anthony Russo, Joe Russo
```